# Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS No Screen Sharing Option

Tags: 18.04, screen, lts, sharing

Under settings, sharing there is no option for Screen Sharing however on another machine with exactly the same image there is an option for Screen Sharing. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi there, i didnt have that issue myself, but you could try reinstalling vino.
`vino/bionic,now 3.22.0-3ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
  VNC server for GNOME`
Of course you should update: `sudo apt-get update` and then just reinstall: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall vino` Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Thanks for this however, still hasn't made any difference. I have computer name below in the Sharing menu in Settings however I do not have the "Screen Sharing" option below it. However on another Ubuntu machine I do. I have reinstalled it many times but still the same. Could it be hardware related?

Comment: @PaddyNewton I don't know if you've already have it solved (has been a year since), but (after having installed vino) I logged out, clicked on the cog wheel next to Sign In and selected "Ubuntu", NOT Ubuntu on Wayland. After logging in, I did have the option for screen sharing.

Comment: i install   vino then I can see  screen sharing option  in my  ubuntu I  use latest ubuntu version

Answer (score 23):

You are likely talking about minimal installation of Ubuntu 18.04, which doesn't provide vino. So just:

> sudo apt-get install vino

the option is back!

Comment: This was my issue as well. I forgot I used minimal. I would also recommend the other answer of enabling dconf-editor after installing vino. The basic settings dont work due to bug in Ubuntu since 2014. Using dconf-editor one has to disable "encryption" so clients like Mac can connect

Comment: Took me a while to find this! Totally saved me!

Answer (score 1):

Install dconf Editor

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Open it and go to /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/ you may find the settings there.

[image: /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/]