# Unable to find ScreenSharing option in Settings on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wayland, vino, obs-studio

Other people have a `screen-sharing` option in the settings->sharing. But I don't have it. From [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1128500/1067851) answer, I realized that the minimal installation is the root cause. Although I have tried that solution, it won't show for me.

I need that option for using obs screen-recorder on Wayland. [This](https://github.com/fzwoch/obs-gnome-screencast) project needs that screen-sharing option to be enabled, so I can record the complete screen.

Expected:
[image]

What I see
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late to the party, but: Install the vino package. It is the VNC server. After that your options will appear.